# ModuleNotFoundError while importing 'emoji' in Jupyter

Tags: python, macos, emoji, python-module

I get an error when I import the emoji into my Jupyter notebook.

This is the error I'm getting.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/8v/gry0pxmn7tq64rhkjv504zr00000gn/T/ipykernel_12578/2329533640.py in <module>
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 import emoji
      5 from collections import Counter
      6 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'emoji'
```

I am using MacOs. How do I solve this?

Comment: install the emoji library: `pip install emoji`. You cannot import a library if you don't install it first

Comment: thank you. i hadnt installed the emoji library

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the library?
For the installation process via pip:

```
pip install emoji --upgrade
```

or via git:

```
git clone https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji.git
cd emoji
python setup.py install
```

That being done, you can import **emoji** into your code.

For further information you can read the installation process on the documentation [here](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/#installation).

Comment: Thank you,i hadnt installed the emoji library. its work now.

Comment: @Sheila Happy to help. Could you please mark this answer as accepted, so that others with similar problems can find a solution easly?

Comment: yes, would do that.